# How to properly use fscanf in this file

Tags: c, scanf

I have this file with the following contents:

> Bob Human, 1
>
> John Cat, 3
>
> Mary Dog, 2

How can I properly use `fscanf` to have each string and integer in a struct.

```
typedef struct {
    char name[20];
    char surname[20];
    int code;
} entry;
```

Then I create an array of `_entry_`

```
entry a[3];
```

How will `_a_` get each value properly using `fscanf`?

EDIT :

I have tried this:

```
while(TRUE) {
    nscan=fscanf(infile, "%s %s d%c", temp.name, temp.surname, &temp.code, &termch);
    if(nscan==EOF) break;
    if(nscan!=4 || termch!='\n') {
        printf("Error\n");
    }
    RecBSTInsert(&a, temp);
}
```

But it seems to pass the last line twice.

Comment: @breathtaker Do not add that much code on comments. Edit the question and add it there.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/  check this so you can understand better fscanf

Comment: For the return value check; instead of `== EOF`, do `!= 4`.  You want to bust out if it did not read the whole line correctly.  If your file does not end in a newline then you might want to accept `3`, store the entry and then break out of the loop

Comment: Also, change `%s` to `%19s` to avoid havoc, and you'll need to take the comma out of `surname`. You could use the `[` specifier to try and automatically handle the comma but that's probably more complicated than just looking for it and overwriting it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [reading using fscanf() for multiple values (as in the text file below)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19407441/reading-using-fscanf-for-multiple-values-as-in-the-text-file-below)

Comment: if you know how many lines you have in the file, you can make a counter variables ex: count = 2; while counter >=0 {do stuff; counter--}

Comment: @MattMcNabb it still passes a line twice. Something weird is that if i simply add a `printf` there the code will run perfectly and the last line will not be read twice

Comment: @breathtaker your current code should break when it gets `Error`, instead of printing error and continuing. Other than that, it won't call `RecBSTInsert` twice for the same line

Comment: "How do I use fscanf" has a lot of questions and answers already. This is a question-and-answer site, not a please-debug-my-program-for-me site.

Comment: @Dragos even if doing that, you still need to check that it reads each line correctly so that doesn't seem to gain anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct{
    char name[20];
    char surname[20];
    int code;
} entry;

int main(){
    entry temp, a[3];
    FILE *infile = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    int i=0, n;
    while(fscanf(infile, "%19s %19[^,], %d", temp.name, temp.surname, &temp.code)==3){
        a[i++] = temp;
        if(i==3)break;
    }
    fclose(infile);
    n = i;
    for(i=0;i<n;++i){
        printf("%s %s, %d\n", a[i].name, a[i].surname, a[i].code);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The thing is that the input file will not always have 3 values to check with `if(i==3)break;`

Comment: @breathtaker ; Limit which was derived from `entry a[3];`.

Comment: Yes i got it. But if i dont know how many entries are in a file, will the while loop stop properly or i need to add an extra break?

Comment: @breathtaker ; It is assumed that there is a need to extend by realloc first secured by malloc if unable to provide the maximum expected the sequence stored in advance.

Comment: or use something like a linked list .

Answer (score 1):

You're close, but you're not handling the comma properly.

As usual, it's much easier to read whole lines, *then* parse them. So let's do that.

Try:

```
char line[1024];

if(fgets(line, sizeof line, infile) != NULL)
{
  nscan = sscanf(line, "%s %[^,], %d", temp.name, temp.surname, &temp.code);
}
```

The return value will be `3` if all the fields converted, else you have an error.

Comment: He is also doing `%c` to check that the newline immediately follows the int; without this then the code will not detect some flavours of malformed input

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yeah, that looked complicated. :) I rewrote it to use the much-recommended approach of reading from the file first, and parsing later.